# error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found when using std::upper_bound

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Consider the following program

```
struct slot {
    int item;
    bool operator<(const int& right) const {
        return item < right;
    }
    slot(int item) : item(item) {}
};
int main() {
    std::vector<slot> rails;
    std::lower_bound(cbegin(rails), cend(rails), 5);
    std::upper_bound(cbegin(rails), cend(rails), 5);
}
```

I am using std::upper_bound to binary search a vector but fails while compiling

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm(2609): error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
```

Considering the fact that `std::upperbound` uses `operator<` for implicit comparison without using a predicate, I cannot find a justified reason for the compiler to complain. Moreover, the error message is not quite meaningful as I do not see a reason for using a surrogate function here. Even if it is a case of using a functor `less<>`, it should not be an issue as `slot` is less comparable with an integer. It's worth noting that `std::lower_bound` has an acceptable syntax.

Refer: http://rextester.com/WKK72283

Comment: Where's the `return` in your operator implementation?

Comment: @AnT: Though the return should be there but that should not be the reason for compile to fail

Comment: You'll find the rest in my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the specifications of `std::upper_bound` clearly states, it applies the comparison with the argument value on the left-hand side and the sequence element on the right-hand side. I.e. in your case that would be `int < slot` comparison. Your `operator <` does not support comparisons arranged in that specific order.

For `std::upper_bound` you'll need

```
bool operator <(int left, const slot &s)
{
  return left < s.item;
}
```

which cannot be implemented as a member function.

Meanwhile, `std::lower_bound` applies the comparisons with the argument value on the right-hand side, i.e. `slot < int` comparisons.

Your original implementation will work for `std::lower_bound`, but not for `std::upper_bound`.

Comment: Yes that is the answer I was looking for. Moreover, at least to me this was not quite intuitive until I referred the standard 25.4.3.2 `Returns: The furthermost iterator i in the range [first,last] such that for any iterator j in the
range [first,i) the following corresponding conditions hold: !(value < *j) or comp(value, *j)
== false.`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the above answer your problem can be solved if the `operator <` can be implemented to take 2 arguments but this will contradict to the member function implementation. But what if this becomes a `friend` function. It turns out the above problem can be solved by declaring it a friend function.

So your code will look something similar to this:

```
struct slot {
    int item;

    friend bool operator<(int left, const slot &s)
    {
        return left < s.item;
    }

    friend bool operator<(const slot &s, int left)
    {
        return s.item < left;
    }

    slot(int item) : item(item) {}
};
```