# operator< gives operator __surrogate_func error

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I've implemented `operator<` for my c++ classes and when I tried it for a class that contains object vector; it fails and gives **operator __surrogate_func**

When I remove object vector from class, everything is OK.
I found this similar question about question but I dont know why Im getting this error? Because I'm just comparing vector. [error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found when using std::upper_bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940394/error-c2672-operator-surrogate-func-no-matching-overloaded-function-found/42166464)

```
class A
{
public:
A() {}

inline int getAVal() { return m_a; }
inline int getBVal() { return m_b; }

inline void setAVal(int a) { m_a = a; }
inline void setBVal(int b) { m_b = b; }

inline bool operator<(const A& r)
{
    return std::tie(m_a, m_b) < std::tie(r.m_a, r.m_b);
}

private:
int m_a;
int m_b;
};

class B
{
B() {}

inline bool operator<(const B& r)
{
    return std::tie(m_aVec) < std::tie(r.m_aVec);
}

private:
std::vector<A> m_aVec;
};
```

Comment: `inline` is redundant for member functions that are defined inside the class definition. Such functions are implicitly `inline` (= "may have definitions in more than one translation unit").

Comment: I don't know why MSVC gives such a cryptic error, but the solution is to declare `operator<` as const: `bool operator<(const A& r) const`.

Comment: @cpplearner Can you elaborate it? Because it works.